# Getting OSError: libnccl.so.2 while importing mxnet

Tags: nvidia, mxnet

My configurations are:

```
gpu: Nvidia GeForce MX450 with 2GB Graphics Card
Cuda version: 10.1
MxNet Version: mxnet-cu101: 1.8.0
```

While trying to mxnet using `import mxnet` I am getting the following error:

```
OSError: libnccl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have been using mxnet for last 2years, but never faced the issue before. As far as I knew mxnet installed them on their own as dependencies. However it didn't happen this time.

Comment: "Starting from version 1.8.0, CUDNN and NCCL should be installed as well." https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.8.0/get_started?platform=linux&language=python&processor=gpu&environ=pip&

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens only in mxnet-cu101==1.8.0 version. I downgraded to mxnet-cu101==1.7 and the problem got fixed.

Comment: Thank you soooooooooo much for this great point shot solution. deeply appreciated

Answer (score 1):

or you can upgrade to newer version:

```
pip install mxnet-cu110==2.0.0a0
```

this solved the issue